# AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'Choropleth'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth map using the data frame below. I'm receiving the error message "AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'Choropleth'"

```
df.head()

Postal Code Latitude    Longitude   Average Price
0   M1B 43.806686   -79.194353  918753
1   M1C 43.784535   -79.160497  1550380
2   M1E 43.763573   -79.188711  1292886
3   M1G 43.770992   -79.216917  969335
4   M1H 43.773136   -79.239476  1013337

df.dtypes()

Postal Code       object
Latitude         float64
Longitude        float64
Average Price     object
dtype: object


#Create a map

ontario_geo = "C:\\Users\\Almas\\Desktop\\torontomap.geojson"

map_toronto = folium.Map(location=[43.653963, -79.387207], zoom_start=10)

map_toronto.Choropleth(geo_data=ontario_geo,
    data = df,
    columns=['Postal Code','Average Price'],
    key_on='feature.properties.insee',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Toronto Home Values',).add_to(map_toronto) 

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_toronto)
    
map_toronto
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that `map_toronto.Choropleth` makes sense? The error message suggests that it does not.

Comment: @John Coleman

If you use the old method "folium.choropleth" you get the:

"FutureWarning: The choropleth  method has been deprecated. Instead use the new Choropleth class, which has the same arguments. See the example notebook 'GeoJSON_and_choropleth' for how to do this."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
    folium.Choropleth(geo_data=ontario_geo,
      data = df,
      columns=['Postal Code','Average Price'],
      key_on='feature.properties.insee',
      fill_color='YlOrRd',
      fill_opacity=0.7, 
      line_opacity=0.2,
      legend_name='Toronto Home Values',).add_to(map_toronto)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the 'Average Price' column from object to integer.